# Django не видит созданный модуль

Tags: python-3.x, django

Django не хочет видеть созданный модуль, я добавлял его в settnigs.py, у модуля есть **init**.py
Когда я пытаюсь сделать include в urls.py, при запуске сервера, выдаёт исключения типа "ModuleNotFoundError" No module named 'chat.urls'[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `chat.urls` очевидно не существует, и это видно на вашем скриншоте

Comment: Ооой, вот я дурак, спасибо тебе друг!